# Como setar Jenkins com formato de 24 horas

Tags: jenkins

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso setar o Jenkins com formato de 24 horas, pois atualmente ele está com formato 12 horas.

Já encontrei tópicos que falam como alterar na língua inglesa, eu quero alterar o horário mas permanecer na língua portuguesa.

Answer (score 0):

Acesse o menu Gerenciar Jenkins -> Configurar o sistema, na área **Timestamper** configure a máscara de tempo que mais te agradar.
Eu utilizo:

System clock time format

```
'<b>'HH:mm:ss'</b>'
```

Elapsed time format

```
'<b>'HH:mm:ss.S'</b>'
```